# Positioning Android views on top of a bitmap

Tags: android-layout, android

I have an ImageView with a bitmap drawable. There are different versions of the bitmap for each device density (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc).

I want to position a TextView on top of the ImageView, and relative to the ImageView's position. e.g. 30px from the right, 50px from the top. The TextView needs to always be displayed in a certain part of the image, so its position will be different for each version of the image created for different screen densities.

Positioning with pixels seems to work. I'm able to create different XML layout files with pixel values for the different versions of the image (hdpi, xhdpi, etc). However, I'm not able to specify px units in dimen.xml

Is positioning with pixels the correct method here? Will positioning with pixels relative to the image work across different devices?

Comment: can you please explain more what certain part of image ?

Comment: The text needs to always fit inside a shape which is part of the image.

Comment: Check out my ans :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610493/set-text-on-button-with-button-backround-and-text-background-differently/24610835#24610835

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. Place a **RelativeLayout** above your **ImageView** and set its color to `#66cccccc. And put a **TextView** in it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImage" />

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="#66cccccc">

        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#fff"
         android:text="Test Description" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using a FrameLayout for the z-ordering. And then I'm positioning the TextView by setting margin in pixels.  The TextView can't be relatively positioned, it needs to be positioned absolutely using pixels with respect to the Image underneath. Will that still work on different devices?

Comment: Actually I've never used `FrameLayout` and I don't have idea about your problem. But I think you can create two different emulator to see differences. (And thank you for upvote).