# Android - Set text inside imageview with gridview

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, android-viewholder

I would like to set the text inside the image view. At the moment I get the image from drawable, even though I think it is better to use a viewholder? here is my adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,

    };
}
```

here is my layout I want to use:
item_single.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/single"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have seen this question [How can I add a TextView into an ImageView in GridView Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101864/how-can-i-add-a-textview-into-an-imageview-in-gridview-layout)
but there is no clear explanation. In that example he uses a ViewHolder, mine keep wanting me to use RecycleViewHolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inflate

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    View view; 
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes 
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout. item_single,false);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else { 
        view = convertView;
        imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);
    } 

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    textView.setText("Any Text");
    return view;
}
```

I would recommend you to use viewholders but as per your requirement you should do it this way.

Comment: `view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_single,false);` can't resolve method inflate(int, boolean)

Comment: Ok, got it to work. What if I want to increment the textview by 1 on each imageview?

Answer (score 0):

Inflate your Custom View in which you have `ImageView` and `TextView` both. Inside your `getView` method of `Adapter` class, some

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
     // This view will contain TextView and ImageView
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
```

For more search custom `Adapter` example.